# Android Framework - how to register new package?

Tags: android, frameworks, android-source

I'm adding a new package in android framework in /base/packages/,
while compiling and building I'm getting an error that package
"com.xx.xxxxxx not exist"
Do I need to register this new package somewhere in framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess yes. Try to add your package into `build/target/product/core.mk` into `PRODUCT_PACKAGES`.

Comment: thanks yury, 
i think this information helps me a lot, but can you tell me it is mandatory to add our new package in that list?  and if we are adding our package in some other place then also we have to register in this same file or somewhere else? 
actually i have an application which i want to make it as a base application which will work as a service, (which will not display in application list). so can you suggest me which is the right place to add that package?

Comment: It actually depends on your need. What do you want to do in general? Do you want to make a new ROM that will be distributed around? Is this ROM for one device or for different?
The right place for user packages are /packages/apps/. But if you want them not to be visible in the full application list then this is not the right place. I did not work with frameworks/base/packages but I guess that applications will not be visible from this place.
Actually, you can put your package name in several places. But I usually put in the place I mentioned because this mk file included in all configurations.